# Custom role can't create permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, user-roles

My user post a new custom type "artprim_item" and it doesn't work unless I remove permalinks. The item is created, but the permalink links to "item not found".

More importantly, if I open the item with my admin account and update it, the permalink works at last.

Since I only want him to see "artprim_item" and no "page, posts, links...)" , this user has a role that I created with limited capacities:

- delete_artprim_item
- edit_artprim_item
- edit_artprim_items
- edit_others_artprim_items
- publish_artprim_items
- read_artprim_item
- read_private_artprim_items
- upload_files
- edit_files
- read

Is there a capacities to create permalinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that it works if I add the `edit_posts` capacity.

But `Posts` is now visible in Admin :(

At the same time, it also fixed a problem I had with Media upload: the user could never edit right after the upload.